# DBCP Pool using same connection?

Tags: java, tomcat, synchronization, oracle11g, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm using JMetric to test my DBCP pool. Using one test with 20 threads I receive nullPointerException when I'm trying to createStatement from one Connection.

My context have this conf:

```
<Context path="/MyApp" docBase="mypath..." crossContext="true" debug="1" reloadable="true" privileged="true" >
        <Resource name="jdbc/orcl"
           auth="Container"
           type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
           driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.11:1521:orcl"
           user="....."
           password="....."
           implicitCachingEnabled="true"
           connectionCachingEnabled="true"
           connectionCacheProperties="{InitialLimit=20, MinLimit=50, MaxLimit=350, MaxStatementsLimit=0, ConnectionWaitTimeout=10}"
           connectionCacheName="cacheOrcl"
           validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
           removeAbandoned="true"
           maxIdle="350"
           removeAbandonedTimeout="45"
           logAbandoned="true"  
            />

    </Context>
```

I have one filter that get a connection and perform some selects. To reuse the logic to get the connection I create one static method:

```
public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws ConnectionException {

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Object o = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/orcl");
        if( o instanceof DataSource ) {
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) o;
            con = ds.getConnection();
            LOGGER.debug("conn:" + con);
        }
    }catch( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.error(LogError.logError(e));
    }

    if( con == null ) {
        throw new ConnectionException("Conn null");
    }

    return con;
}
```

And my filter:

```
try {
        if( session.getAttribute(PARAM) == null ) {
            conexao = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
            //call DAOS... (ommited)
        }
    }catch( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.error( LogError.logError(e) );
    } finally {
        try{ 
            conexao.close();
            conexao = null;
        }catch( Exception e ){}
    }
```

To receive the NullPointerException I think that the getConnection() from DataSource is retreaving one connection that still in use.

Is a problem have one static synchronized method to get the connection from the pool?

The NullPointerException:

```
Statement st = conexao.createStatement();
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying the tomcat-jdbc now. He seems to handle better the opened connections but still fails in concurrent users (same NullPointerException or sometimes java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.)

Comment: On Psi-Probe (http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) I can see that the connections still busy even after I expire all sessions.

Comment: Where is the stacktrace for the NPE?  Are you sure that the NPE is NOT coming out of your finally block?  What if conexao is null?  NPE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fight I saw that I had one private attribute of type Connection inside my Spring Controller. I commented this attribute and declared connection inside my method and this solved my problem.